# Unable to get -r parameter working

Tags: console2

I've tried in every way imaginable to execute a shell command from command line but it simply doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
C:\Console2\Console.exe -r runstuff.bat

C:\Console2\Console.exe -d C:\Console2 -r runstuff.bat

C:\Console2\Console.exe -r dir
```

Neither works. (Win7 x64)

Comment: Try ConEmu instead? Example command: "ConEmu.exe /cmd cmd.exe /k dir"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am playing with that now.

Did you try:

```
console2 -r "/K runstuff.bat"
```

The /K is needed to keep the command open after running the script.

The problem I'm having with the "-r" option is that I'm having to type exit twice to leave the window.

If you add the command to shell command (settings... -> Tabs -> Shell) field you will not have to type exit twice:

```
%comspec% /K runstuff.bat
```

I don't think the "%comspec%" is necessary (could use "cmd" instead), but I got it from an example somewhere on the web years ago.  Console2's included help file shows using "cmd".